# What's the meaning of 'tote a megaphone'?

Tags: meaning

I think it literally means carrying a megaphone but I don't know why it is written there. 
Please tell me.

> So that tiny voice in the back of your head telling you "I need a seat on this overcrowded bus -- stat!" is suddenly ***toting a megaphone***, which helps you go with your gut and do what's best for you and your baby.

Comment: Research the word "tote" that should give you all you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

The author is using a figure of speech. The "tiny voice" in your head is now speaking very loudly, as if using a megaphone to get your attention.